# What's the purpose of this small hole in shower arm base

Tags: bathroom, shower

As shown in the picture, this small hole is splashing out water after turning on the water for a while (to be more precise, it splashes out a bit of water immediately after turning on the water, then stops, after a while it then constantly splashes out water).
[image]

Comment: Water should not be in that section, the wet section of pipe is smaller.  Purpose of the hole at a guess is for locking set screw.  Will need to take it apart to see if a seal is leaking or the water pipe is leaking.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like it is a pressure relief valve for the pipe, possibly for freeze protection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).